# Trouble with Dual Booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

So I've been trying to get a dual boot set up. The problem is that Ubuntu doesn't detect Windows 8 during installation making my only options erase the whole drive or partition manually.

I sectioned off about half the drive (350gb), but whenever I tell it to use that portion it tells me it has no root driver.

So my issue could probably be fixed two ways:
1) help me get Ubuntu to recognize that the system already has an OS.
or
2) help me figure out why it isn't using the 350gb to partition.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

while installing ubuntu you have to mount the partition you want it to install on as / (root drive). you can have more partitions for /home, /usr, /var and any other folders / subfolders you would want to keep if you reinstall / change linux distribution.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try install boot-repair

```
sudo apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

then ,run the boot-repair GUI and choose repair boot loader